# Magento - Use symbolic links - Don't work correctly - why ?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2

I'm trying to have a magento structure to we can use in multiple sites, like I do with other products like Drupal.

I'd like to have :

```
index.php ----> [path]/index.php
```

where index.php is not a file. Is a symbolic link what point to file.

When I try to load this index.php in version 2.1 directly dont work and in version 1.9 don't work admin form.

Why ?

Is possible to have index.php as a link ?

Thanks.

Ricardo / Brqx.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create symlink for a file. 
Please make sure that you enable FollowSymLinks on your directory. 
Then you should check permission of the file, Apache user should be able to access to both folders. 
Finally, you can try to use FULL PATH for the symlink. Good luck!